# Issue MySQL 8.0 ODBC 8.0

Tags: mysql, odbc

Sorry for my English but I am french
**Presentation**
I have developed a small « ERP » application using the following environment
Windows10, VBA Excel 2016 as client and MySQL 8.0  as Server (Amazon)
ODBC Driver 8.0 for Windows

All of that is going well until now.

But I have reinstalled my development PC from scratch (Windows 10, office 2016, ODBC and MySQL ) and I have an issue (coming probably from ODBC).

Most of classical SQL code are OK.

But the SQL code using rscount is no more working.

Example:

```
Dim requete as String
Set Rs = New ADODB.RecordsetB 
requete = "SELECT col1, col2, ... 
FROM Table1, ...
WHERE condition ... "
Rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Rs.Open requete, cn
rscount = Rs.RecordCount
If rscount = 0 Then    
...
```

I Have a compilation problem (incompatibility of type) on all the lines holding recordcount.

I don’t understand this problem because I used the same versions of all software before the crash and I have not changed anything in my application code
Did MySQL gave up the rscount variable ? Do I need a specific library to handle it?

I would be very glad if somebody from your community could help me because this issue is blocking and I have used a lot of times the recordcount variable

Best regards

Comment: Actually I think this is better to the dba forum

Comment: IIRC depending on cursor type, `Recordset.RecordCount` yields the number of records *accessed*, not the number of records in the recordset. What is the declared type of `rscount`? Is it declared at all? FWIW a "type mismatch" **compile-time** error has nothing whatsoever to do with MySQL: if the code doesn't compile, the problem is with the VBA code.